# strftime first day of current week

Tags: c, sqlite, date, datetime, strftime

```
strftime('%s', 'now', 'start of month') AND strftime('%s', 'now', 'start of month', '+1 month', '-1 day')
```

this gives me range between first and last day of current month. How can I get range of current week?

This

```
 strftime('%s', 'now', 'weekday 0')
```

gives seems to give last day of current week(Sunday), but I can't  find how to get first day of current week.

PS: I use strftime in WHERE clause accessing DB in Sqlite

Comment: did you figure out anyway to start the calculation from **6 AM** in the morning till **12 midnight** ? kinda want to see the daily Revenue , `-1 day` will return what's before 6 AM which is not a good option here for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
strftime('%s', 'now', 'weekday 0', '-1 week', '+1 day')

strftime('%s', 'now', 'weekday 0', '-1 day')
```

`weekday` modifier advances the date forward to the next date where the weekday number is N.  Sunday is 0, ...

Comment: I did almost the same - strftime('%s', 'now', 'weekday 0', '-6 day') :-)

Comment: anyway to start the calculation from **6 AM** in the morning till **12 midnight** ? kinda want to see the daily Revenue , `-1 day` will return what's before 6 AM which is not a good option here for me